# Riemann gradients for the log-cholesky metric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, symmetric-matrices, gradient-descent

I am currently working on an optimization problem involving some positive semi-definite (spd) matrices. While looking for a suitable algorithm, I stumbled across Riemann manifold gradient descent (RMGD).
In https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.09326 the space of spd matrices $\mathcal{S}_+$ has been equipped with a metric induced by the $\log$-Cholesky metric on the space of lower-triangular matrices with positive diagonals $\mathcal{L}_+ $.
For $X,Y\in T_L\mathcal{L}_+ (=\mathcal{L})$
$$\tilde{g}_L(X,Y) = \sum_{i>j}X_{ij}Y_{ij} + \sum_{j=1}^{m}X_{j}Y_{jj}L_{jj}^{-2}$$
which induces the metric for spd matrices
$$g_P(W,V) = \tilde{g}_{\mathcal{L}(P)}((D_P\mathcal{L})(W), (D_P\mathcal{L})(V))$$
$$D_P\mathcal{L}: W \rightarrow \mathcal{L}(P)( \mathcal{L}(P)^{-1}W\mathcal{L}(P)^{-\top})_{\frac{1}{2}}$$
where $\mathcal{L}(\cdot)$ denotes the Cholesky decomposition of a matrix.
The question now is how we evaluate a gradient in this Riemannian manifold? I know, that for a smooth loss function $f(\cdot): \mathcal{S}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the gradient on the Riemann manifold at a point $P\in\mathcal{S}_+$ should be given by
$$g_P(grad (f), v ) = df(v)$$
for $v\in T_P\mathcal{S}_+$.
But how would you actually obtain the gradient in this case?

Comment: By computing $df$ (partial derivatives) and [raising an index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raising_and_lowering_indices).